# Adding a CSS file with custom font (font-face)

Tags: css, fonts, firefox-addon, font-face, custom-font

I try to include a CSS file with custom font (via using @font-face)

**Lib/main.js :**

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentStyleFile: [self.data.url("css/fontello/fontello.css")]
});
```

*(This work correctly, tested by adding background-color)*

But I think I have problem to local **font path**..

**This is my folder look like**

[image]

And my **fontello.css** with @font-face look like.. *(This is just a part of fontello)*

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('fontello.eot?25255831');
  src: url('fontello.eot?25255831#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('fontello.woff?25255831') format('woff'),
       url('fontello.ttf?25255831') format('truetype'),
       url('fontello.svg?25255831#fontello') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

After this , I try to add a element with my custom font, It doesnt work

**What is this src sholud be ?**

---

Tested :

```
data/css/fontello/fontello.{font-ex}
/data/css/fontello/fontello.{font-ex}
css/fontello/fontello.{font-ex}
/css/fontello/fontello.{font-ex}
fontello/fontello.{font-ex}
/fontello/fontello.{font-ex}
fontello.{font-ex}
/fontello.{font-ex}
```

Noone works :(

Comment: the Network tab Chrome Inspector should be able to tell you if the font files are getting loaded correctly. I think your paths in the fontello.css are correct, but is the css file itself getting loaded correctly?

Comment: @PeterVR Yes, loaded correctly , I tested by adding `body {background:#f00}` in `fontello.css` file. And its work. Now I use base64 its work fine now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give up ! I encoded font in Base64 like...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'fontello';
  src: url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,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') format('woff'),
       url('data:application/octet-stream;base64,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') format('truetype');
}
```